# Angular2 reactive forms select how to set invalid?

Tags: forms, angular, select, reactive

I use reactive forms within my app. In a certain form I want to display a **required** (Validators.required) select like this:

```
<select class="form-control"
        [id]="dformControl.key"
        [formControlName]="dformControl.key"
        [multiple]="dformControl.multiple">

  <option *ngIf="!dformControl.value"
          value="undefined">
    Choose ...
  </option>

   <option *ngFor="let opt of dformControl.options"
          [value]="opt.value"
          [selected]="dformControl.value == opt.value">
    {{opt.label}}
  </option>

</select>
```

The problem is whether I use `value="undefined"` or `value=""` the form control still is set to valid because it got a value. Do not present the `value` attribute results in `value="Choose ..."`.

Am I using select with reactive forms in a false way or how would I be able to make the option "Choose ..." being not **valid**??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is add a blank option and when that is selected since there is no value it is not valid.

```
<select class="form-control"
        [id]="dformControl.key"
        [formControlName]="dformControl.key"
        [multiple]="dformControl.multiple">

  <option></option>
   <option *ngFor="let opt of dformControl.options"
          [value]="opt.value"
          [selected]="dformControl.value == opt.value">
    {{opt.label}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: kind of weird cause that even doesn't do the trick for me .. switching to a valid option an switching back to the blank option leaves the form control status valid

Comment: @MaxSolid if all you have is Validator.required it shouldn't I just tested now.

Comment: @MaxSolid https://plnkr.co/edit/OaMTzUbUzsh6pPyRptNP?p=preview here is a plunkr look how it is behaving, it is reactive form html.

Answer (score 3):

Assigning initial value of select control to `null` will do the trick. Try below,

```
  model_property = null

  ....
  this.fb.group({ 
  .... 
  'control_key'  :    [this.model_property, Validators.required]
  ...
  })
```

Check this [Plunker!!](https://plnkr.co/edit/lZ5FOxpvRvH9RFZ2z79T?p=preview), Look into `app/reactive/hero-form-reactive.component.ts` file.

I updated the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lZ5FOxpvRvH9RFZ2z79T?p=preview) to include below and it seems to be working,

```
    <select id="power" class="form-control"
        formControlName="power" required >

        // see the value is set to empty,
        <option value="">Choose...</option>

        <option *ngFor="let p of powers" [value]="p">{{p}}</option>
    </select>
```

[image]

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Using `''` or `null` for initial value does not make any difference. Initially the form control is set to invalid in both ways. The problem I meant was that if I change the select to a certain option and then switch back to option **Choose ...** the form control is still valid

Comment: @MaxSolid: Updated the Plunker, not sure if it the scenario you are talking about. If not can you try updating the Plunker to reproduce your scenario.

Comment: Seems like the problem I had is related to `[multiple]="dformControl.multiple"`. After I removed this line everything worked as it should. `dformControl.multiple` was undefined and `multiple` was not added to the `<select>` tag. Don't know why that has had any influence on the status of the form control.